# Strong Name for DocuSign.eSign.dll

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to implement DocuSign within C# using the SDK DocuSign.eSign.dll. I need to sign the final assembly and is moaning about the Docusign assembly not being signed.

I have tried various methods of signing the dll

1. StrongNameSigner project
2. Using ildasm and ilasm

They appear to work, however when the code is run in debug mode as soon as any DocuSign.eSign member method is executed an exception is thrown.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You must be on an older version of the DLL as the dll was signed on 3/7/16, which is `v2.0.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Bradders, what version of DocuSign.eSign are you using?

You should be using v2.0.1 which is a signed package that was published on March 7, 2016.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I was using the assembly in the SDK test example, which is not signed.